# Open mobile keyboard in specific language from html

Tags: android, html, iphone

There is a way to open mobile keyboard from html
in specific language when i press on input filed (iphone or android)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any information about android's keyboard.. But on iphone, you cannot manage keyboard language from UIWebView component. This means you cannot open iphone keyboard in specific language from html(you call it like that). It depends on user only.

You can only open the keyboard in specific language on native application with using apple private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is not possible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: He asked for a way. And there's no way. So what's the answer gonna be?